# Trying to make php elseif post condition but not working

Tags: php, if-statement, post

I'm trying to make some php else if but seems to have some trouble making post method work. Here's the condition:

```
        <?php if (!$yes_good) { ?>

        <form action='/' method='post'>

          <input type="hidden" name="GOOD" value="1" />

          <input id="linkid" class="label" type="submit" value="" name='' />

        </form>


    <?php } else { ?>

        <form action='/' method='post'>  

          <input type="hidden" name="BAD" value="1" />

          <input id="linkid" class="label" type="submit" value="" name='' />

        </form>


        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Result page:

```
    <?php if (isset($_POST['GOOD'])): ?>

  <h1> GOOD! </h1>

<?php elseif (isset($_POST['BAD'])): ?>

 <h1> BAD! </h1>

<?php else: ?>

 <!-- Shows up when form is bypass or page is access directly. -->
 <h1> Not GOOD or BAD </h1> 


<?php endif; ?>
```

The php elseif post method seems not working.

UPDATE:  there was a code conflicting. this example here is actually working without problem, just some messy code causing problem.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($_POST);` before everything to see what was actually sent.

Comment: <?php elseif (isset($_POST['BAD'])): ?> this one seems not working

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: when accessing the result page (bypassing the form) it should show <h1> Not GOOD or BAD </h1>. but it is not, instead it shows both elseif and else.

Comment: when the second form is triggered - it doesn't show <h1> BAD! </h1>

Comment: I just tried it and I get `Not GOOD or BAD` when I go to the page directly. http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test_elseif.php

Comment: And it works with the form also: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test_elseif_form.php

Comment: that's really strange.. can you post an answer with both two page form and result page?

Comment: My results page is exactly the same as yours. The form page is like yours except without the `if (!$yes_good)`.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer if I can't explain what you did wrong and how my answer fixes it. The problem must be something you didn't show.

Comment: right. it's working, i did some messy codes inside condition 2. thanks anyways!